# Vertical alignment of a list in a table using tblr

Tags: tables, alignment

I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{|X[j,valign=t] | X[j,valign=t]|X[j,valign=t]|X[j,valign=t]|}
  \hline
  Criteria & Sources(s) & Measures & Notes\\
  \hline
  Audience Engagement  & 
      \begin{itemize}][noitemsep] 
         \item TKTKTTK (1999) 
         \item TKTKTKT (2019) 
      \end{itemize} & 
      \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
          \item TKTKTKTKT
          \item TKTKTKTKTT
      \end{itemize} & 
      fj; lfjalkjf;asdljfsdl; jfal;djfla jd; jlasdjf;ljf;ldj fla;dsj f;alj fadjljd\\
  \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
```

and the output is:

[image: table]

The first and last columns are vertically aligned to the top but the middle two, which have the lists, are centered. Any way to fix this please?

Comment: Maybe you can read doc of `tabularray` about `varwidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}   % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, itemsep=3pt, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[l] X[l] X[l] X[l] },  % <--- changed
             stretch=-1,        % <---
             measure = vbox     % <---
              }
Criteria    
    &   Sources(s)      
        &   Measures    
            &   Notes           \\
Audience Engagement  
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   TKTKTTK (1999)
    \item   TKTKTKT (2019)
        \end{itemize}   
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item TKTKTTK (1999)
        \item TKTKTKT (2019)
            \end{itemize}   
            &   fj; lfjalkjf; asdljfsdl; jfal; djfla jd; jlasdjf; ljf; ldj fla; dsj f; alj fadjljd                 \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko - perfect!